# OAuth Prompt for Microsoft Graph does not display prompt in Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I'm trying to get my user to authenticate with Microsoft Graph. I've been trying to use one of the Microsoft examples: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph
It asks for a string `'ConnectionSettingName'` which it then uses in the `OAuthHelpers.cs` class for the `OAuthPrompt Prompt`, however the prompt accepts (and does not error) the string regardless of what is inputted as the `ConnectionSettingName` and does not prompt the user within the emulator. When debugging I see that this `OAuthPrompt Prompt` below attempts to run, but nothing gets returned.

```
    public static OAuthPrompt Prompt(string connectionName)
    {
        return new OAuthPrompt(
            "loginPrompt",
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = connectionName,
                Text = "Please login",
                Title = "Login",
                Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
            });
    }
```

It then bypasses this and goes on to show the welcome card in the emulator. If I click on any of the options to query the `Graph (Me, Logout, Help, etc...)` the emulator freezes as I have not been able to authenticate yet. Could anyone give some insights on why my `OAuthPrompt` is not displaying?

As a note, within the bot framework emulator under App settings I've checked the boxes 'Use a sign-in verification code for `OAuthCards`'. I've tried this with it both on and off with no results.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Which version of the emulator are you using? Have you set up an AAD app already?  [This may help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: I'm using 4.0.9 alpha version of the emulator. I have set up an AAD app and followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp . When I refresh app I get this error: Refresh access token failed with status code: 401, and references the node modules within the app.asar file for the emulator.

Comment: Is you connection working in azure when you use "test connection"?  ALso can you try to upgrade your emulator to 4.0.0-40025?  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases

Comment: Yes the connection is working. I've upgraded it now, the OAuthPrompt is still being skipped over and the welcome card appears.

Comment: so when you click "me" on the welcome card nothing happens?

Comment: It tries to send and fails, I uploaded a picture of what happens: https://i.imgur.com/yeuFV2j.png

Comment: Are you using your app ID and password in your bot file?  If you are not try that.

Comment: Inputting the app ID and password into the .bot file worked. It allowed the OAuth prompt to appear, and when pressed, a window opens that instructs you to copy the code and paste it into the chat. However, when I paste it in, it just spits the OAuth prompt right back at me and doesn't accept the validation code. https://i.imgur.com/0teIOR9.png

Comment: Got it working - the last problem was an issue with scopes. Need to read readme more closely. Thank you Jason.

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working!